# Opencart Event for success payment and complate

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

In opencart 2.3.x after payment completed we need send email and SMS for customer.

- List of Products
- others information

for example in `post.order.history.add` event execute after payment completed?

for example i write this code in `/analytics`

folder `/admin/extension/analytics/wee.php`

```
class ControllerExtensionAnalyticsWee extends Controller {
    public function install()
    {
        $this->load->model('extension/event');
        $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('wee', 'post.order.history.add','module/wee/cart');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $this->load->model('extension/event');
        $this->model_extension_event->deleteEvent('wee');
    }

    public function cart($id)
    {
        //...
        $admin_mail = $this->config->get('config_email');
        mail($admin_mail, "Email content...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to register a method to your event:

```
$this->event->register('post.order.history.add', 'checkout/order/send_email');
```

Then you can trigger it like:

```
$this->event->trigger('pre.order.history.add', $order_id);
```

Comment: i find `catalog/model/checkout/order/addOrderHistory/after` for event after order, In system 2.3.x opencart choice the new path for event systems